# Заполнить listview при помощи AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

Добрый день! Прошу подсказать, что неправильно делаю! Есть активити, откуда вызывается асинхронная задача. После ее выполнения нужно наполнить лист вью значениями из массива. Асинхронная задача отрабатывает корректно, но лист вью не заполняется значениями. Т.е. на вход listview.setadapter идет пустое значение. Прошу помочь!

```
MainActivity2.class
ArrayList<String> listItems;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
listItems=new ArrayList<String>();
AsyncGetNews getnewstask = new AsyncGetNews();
getnewstask.execute();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Асинхронная задача:

```
private class AsyncGetNews extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        SoapReq so = new SoapReq();
        Helper hp = new Helper();
        String[] temp = so.getLatestNews();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity2.this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        for (String s : temp)
            listItems.add(s);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам setAdapter(), нужно вызывать в AsynkTask, а именно переопределите метод onPostExecute в AsynkTask, в котором сделайте setAdapter() и notifyDaraSetChanged()

Comment: Спасибо, все получилось!